# How to check NSData is String or Image

Tags: ios

How to check NSData is string or image data , i have receive server can get 2 type of data is string and UIImage data. How to check data is string or image data. Thank in advanced.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {

            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventOpenCompleted");
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            if(!self.data) {
                self.data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            }
            while (self.networkStream.hasBytesAvailable) {
                uint8_t buf[1024];

                NSInteger len = 0;
                len = [self.networkStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
                if(len>0) {
                    [self.data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
                    // bytesRead is an instance variable of type NSNumber.
                    self.bytesRead  +=  len; 
                }else{    
                }
            }

            // Event when read input stream done
            if (!self.networkStream.hasBytesAvailable) {

                    [self _didReceiveDataString:self.data];          
            }
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with rmaddy. But check image before string, because image data may return a valid string.

```
if ([UIImage imageWithData:data])
{
    // get image
}else if ([[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])
{
    // get string        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would question a setup that could send string or image with no metadata to tell you which.

But if you always receive the same type of image you can examine the first few bytes to see if it contains the expected "signature".  And most image formats will contain some "illegal" Unicode characters in or immediately following the "signature", so you can detect for sure that it's not a string.

It's kind of clumsy to attempt to convert the data & detect failure in order to determine its type.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to try to create an `NSString` from the data (`NSString initWithData:encoding:`). If that fails, then try to create a `UIImage` (`UIImage imageWithData:`). If that fails, you have neither.

Another option would be to check the data length. This works if you know that the longest string you will get will never be more data than the smallest image you might get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];
if(image != nil){
   // correct image
} else{
   // incorrect image
}
```