# How can I check type of media converted in NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, audio

In the app I've a screen where I am allowing user to add images or recorded audio sounds. I've successfully configured both meaning I've `NSData` of image and `NSData` of recorded sound files in CoreData. I've a media screen containing a `tableView` on which I want to display the attached media. User will be able to view the content meaning if it's an image he can tap on cell and view it or it it's sound it should play the sound.

I've converted tableView to two section with different cells (Cell with Image View, Cell with Play Stop Button) and now I want to display sound in the sound section and images in image section.
My **Question** is that I've both data in NSData form. **How can I convert and find out weather it's a sound or an image file?** If anyone want to see any code I can update my question.

Comment: Don't you know before hand if the kind of data added in CoreData is an audio or an image? If that's the case, add a property on your entity to give the type.

Comment: I suggest storing image and audio file separately in harddisk and store the path in coredata. It will optimize your app. Adding two different entities in coredata one for audio and one for image should do the trick.

Comment: @Larme I tried this way you suggested but I'm stuck at a point. Kindly have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746603/how-to-send-a-value-with-afmultipartformdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check as below :

```
UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
if(image != nil){
   // image
} else{
   // video
}
```

check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27235562/3901620